# Using Gson to parse string to object. Boolean value is always false

Tags: android, gson

I fecht a Json-String from my server:

```
{"erfolgreich":"true","id":"14"}
```

When I call

```
//result is the string above
msgServer = gson.fromJson(result, MsgSpielerErstellenSA.class);
```

The boolean is always false...

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my MsgSpielerErstellenSA

```
public class MsgSpielerErstellenSA {

    private long id;
    private boolean isErfolgreich;

    public MsgSpielerErstellenSA(long id, boolean isErfolgreich) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.isErfolgreich = isErfolgreich;
    }


    public boolean isErfolgreich() {
        return isErfolgreich;
    }

    public void setErfolgreich(boolean isErfolgreich) {
        this.isErfolgreich = isErfolgreich;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you try to return your boolean as a boolean instead of string? Like this: `{"erfolgreich":true,"id":"14"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the correct name for the boolean field is `erfolgreich`, not `isErfolgreich`. Please use the following class:

```
public class MsgSpielerErstellenSA {

    private long id;
    private boolean erfolgreich;

    public MsgSpielerErstellenSA(long id, boolean isErfolgreich) {
        this.id = id;
        this.erfolgreich = isErfolgreich;
    }


    public boolean isErfolgreich() {
        return erfolgreich;
    }

    public void setErfolgreich(boolean isErfolgreich) {
        this.erfolgreich = isErfolgreich;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

But if you don't want to rename this field, you can use `@SerializedName("erfolgreich")` annotation on it

Comment: You are right. I did not regocnize this because the the boolean on server side was also called isErfolgreich. The server just changed into erfolgreich. But y? Becauce there is a boolean and a method which is called same?

Comment: @Bolic it's ok to have field and method with the same name, it's not the reason of change

Answer (score 1):

The name of your key "erfolgreich" in json string should be same as your class data member "isErfolgreich" or you should use @SerializedName notation before define your member. if gson can not match between a class member and json keys, then use the default value for that member type. so you can use the nikis solution or you can use notation like this:

```
@SerializedName("erfolgreich")
private boolean isErfolgreich;
```